# Sentencepiece Tokenizer training from scrath

Tags: nlp, tokenization

To train BPE model on sentencepiece as per given [Usage instructions](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece#usage-instructions)

As, it is mentioned in the instructions that `--input: one-sentence-per-line raw corpus file.`

What if a sentence is long enough and cannot fit in a single line?

is there some documentation/instructions to prepare a dataset as per required format to train BPE model on sentencepiece from scratch?

Comment: There is no limit to the length of a line in a text file, so it's not possible that it "cannot fit"

Comment: @noe got it thanks, does it mean that every sentence should be separated by a new line char?

Comment: Yes, that's it.